# Simple Objective-C Concept

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just wants to know this strange behavior When I am declaring the `NSString *temp` in .h file and in `viewDidLoad` method try to print it is `NSLog(@"%@,temp")` , it is showing the null velue to me but when i declare this variable before `NSLog(@"%@",temp)` my app is getting crashed saying bad access, can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: Please post declration of the `.h` file.

Comment: @reckoenes ViewController : UIViewController{

    NSString *check;
    
}

Comment: @Anshul, edit your question to add the code you're using.  Also, make sure you format it.  [Formatting Docs](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1):

Variables declared as instance variables are set to 0 by default, but local variables are not, i.e. they generally contain invalid data/pointers. When accessing them, you get the crash.

Edit: You can try with int values - they won't crash but show their value. Or dump the pointer value of your object.

Comment: Can you tell me why it has become Instance variable by declaring in .h file or at outside the function

Comment: My *guess* is that you put it into the '@interface .... @end' section, but you didn't provide your code.

Comment: @Anshul it's a concept that if you declare any variable inside the `.h` it becomes the iVar by default.so if want more details knowledge you should take a look of this link https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Introduction/introObjectiveC.html

Comment: what is a iVar and how it get initial value?

Comment: An ivar (or instance variable) is a variable for that very instance. You can initialize it in your init method, for example. It defaults to zero.

Comment: But i am not initializing my NSString object any where in my code but it still show me null.

Comment: As I said: ivars are initialized to 0 = nil = NULL by default. Automatically.

Comment: means if i declare variable inside of function it's not a iVar? Correct

Comment: Yes. But may I suggest to start with a good book on programming - I think there are many concepts that you will need to learn that we cannot get in full detail here.

Comment: @Eiko YES you are right ivars are initialized to 0 = nil = NULL by default. Automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a NSString as ivar then by default it will have nil value. So `NSLog(@"%@", temp)` will show null. But local variable do not get any default initial value, rather they contain garbage value. So in this case `NSLog(@"%@", temp)` is trying to access the invalid address and thus bad access is occurring. You can check this in debugger. ivar will show nil but local string will show a garbage value.

EDIT: An ivar means instance member variable of a class. You declare these variables in `@interface` block. They are not same of global variables which are declared outside of any class and method. Global variables are accessible from any place of the code, but instance variables are accessible inside class (unless of course you have defined setter/getter). The things about crash is if you try to access any memory which is not part of your program then it will crash. An uninitialized variable contain garbage value.

```
NSString *str;
```

Consider this uninitialized `str`. Say it contains garbage value `0x130154d0`. So when you write `NSLog(@"%@", str)` it is trying to access the object at `0x130154d0` which is invalid for the program and will crash.

If you declare this variable as an instance member variable of the class (ivar) then it is already initialized by the compiler to `nil`. And in that case you will see `null` instead of crash.

Comment: it's not so it'll crash either you declared it as iVar or as Localvar.i have checked

Comment: What is ivar and how declaring it in .h makes it a ivar?

Comment: @Anshul iVar(instance) means they can be access inside the `.m`  without any restriction.they treat global variable for corresponding Class

Comment: No, it is being crashed i have checked it many times . When i declare it in .h file it shows null but when i declare it in viewDidLoad and then access it without initial value it is being crashed . it gives me warning trying to access uninitialized value.

Comment: When we call a variable as iVar

Answer (score 1):

it happening because ivars are initialised to 0 = nil = NULL by defaulton based on their typs. Automatically. and other side local variable need to initialise first.

i think, You were doing like this way.

```
  NSString* myName;
  //in this case it'll give the warning VARIABLE "myName" IS UNINITIALIZED WHEN USED HERE.
  NSLog(@"%@",myName)
```

when you will assign some `nil` or any other value it'll not crash.
So You  should do in this way.

```
  NSString* myName= nil;
  NSLog(@"%@",myName);
```

i hope it clears you.